# Hibernate configuration using annotation in JAR module not working in Spring MVC EAR project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jboss

I have created ear project with one web module and one EJB module.

I'm using web module for Spring MVC view and controller. Model, service and repository are maintained in ejb module. (tried in JAR module as well).

`I'm getting exception like, [springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 168) Context initialization failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.sakthi.core.config.HibernateConfiguration Exception.`

Could anyone please help me?

My `HibernateConfiguration` class is,

```
package com.sakthi.core.config;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.sakthi.core.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "root");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "root");
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }

}
```

See the detailed Log below:

```
23:10:09,229 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 168) Context initialization failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.sakthi.core.config.HibernateConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:384)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:231)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.sakthi.imsx.core.config.HibernateConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$13c7c533 is not an enhanced class
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:621)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.registerStaticCallbacks(Enhancer.java:594)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:374)
    ... 24 more

23:10:09,229 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 168) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./imsx-web: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./imsx-web: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.sakthi.imsx.core.config.HibernateConfiguration
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.sakthi.imsx.core.config.HibernateConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:384)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:231)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.sakthi.imsx.core.config.HibernateConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$13c7c533 is not an enhanced class
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:621)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.registerStaticCallbacks(Enhancer.java:594)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:374)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: add your pom.xml

Comment: I have taken the example from the below link. If I try to place service, dao, configuration everything in the web module, it is working fine. But, if I move the core logic to ejb module, I got the error. I'm creating github project to post my full code. will share the link once i uploaded. Meanwhile will this link help? This is what I tried in EAR.  http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-and-hibernate4-integration-example-using-annotations/

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in your configuration above. Update this:

```
    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "root");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "root");
        return properties;        
    }
```

to the following:

```
    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        return properties;        
    }
```

The IllegalStateException Exception may be caused by the fact that "root" is being passed to a boolean property. So it needs to be 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: I'm sorry. While I add the snippet here, instead of editing some other string, I wrongly added "root". But in my code I have correct value "true".

Comment: I have added my codebase in github. Please refer the URL https://github.com/newway86/Spring4MVCHibernateEAR